# Does Windows log when a local user account is created

Tags: user-accounts, administrator, event-viewer, local-groups

I would like to know if windows remembers or logs(maybe event viewer) when a new user account is created then added to the administrators localgroup.

Ex.. 
A network account user creates a local user on a machine called `anonuser` then adds it to the administrators localgroup all through the command line. 
 If another user wants to know who created `anonuser` can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### How do I find out who created a user?

Look for Event ID 4720: A user account was created:

> **4720: A user account was created**
>
> - The user identified by Subject: created the user identified by New Account:.
> - Attributes show some of the properties that were set at the time the account was created.  Notice account is initially disabled.
> - This event is logged both for local SAM accounts and domain accounts.
> - You will see a series of other User Account Management events after this event as the remaining properties are punched down, password set
>   and account finally enabled.
>
> **Subject**:
>
> The user and logon session that performed the action.
>
> - Security ID:  The SID of the account.
> - Account Name: The account logon name.
> - Account Domain: The domain or - in the case of local accounts - computer name.
> - Logon ID is a semi-unique (unique between reboots) number that identifies the logon session.  Logon ID allows you to correlate
>   backwards to the logon event (4624) as well as with other events
>   logged during the same logon session.

See the source link below for a full list of Categories and Subcategories for the event.

Source [4720: A user account was created](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4720)

---

#### How do I find out who added a user the administrators local group?

Look for Event ID 4732: A member was added to a security-enabled local group:

> **4732: A member was added to a security-enabled local group**
>
> - The user in Subject: added the user/group/computer in Member: to the Security Local group in Group:.
> - This event is logged on domain controllers for Active Directory domain local groups and member computer for local SAM groups.  You can
>   determine if the group is a domain or SAM group by comparing Group
>   Domain: to the Computer: name.  If they match you have a SAM group, if
>   they differ you have a domain group.
>
> Active Directory
>
> - In Active Directory Users and Computers "Security Enabled" groups are simply referred to as Security groups. AD has 2 types of groups:
>   Security and Distribution. Distribution (security disabled) groups are
>   for distribution lists in Exchange and cannot be assigned permissions
>   or rights. Security (security enabled) groups can be used for
>   permissions, rights and as distribution lists. A domain local group
>   means the group can only be granted access to objects within its
>   domain but can have members from any trusted domain.
>
> Local SAM
>
> - All groups are security groups in the computer's SAM.  Local SAM groups can be granted access to objects on the local computer only but
>   may have members from the local SAM and any trusted domain.
>
> **Subject**:
>
> The user and logon session that performed the action.
>
> - Security ID:  The SID of the account.
> - Account Name: The account logon name.
> - Account Domain: The domain or - in the case of local accounts - computer name.
> - Logon ID is a semi-unique (unique between reboots) number that identifies the logon session.  Logon ID allows you to correlate
>   backwards to the logon event (4624) as well as with other events
>   logged during the same logon session.

See the source link below for a full list of Categories and Subcategories for the event.

Source [4732: A member was added to a security-enabled local group](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4732)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Windows Security Log Events](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/Default.aspx?catid=2)

Comment: Let's say all the event viewer logs are permanenty wiped. Is it still possible to discover who created `anonuser`?

Comment: @Beall619 In that case I don't think so.